# Weird functional equation $(e^x-1)f(2x)=\left(e^{2x}-1\right)f(x)$

Tags: functions, exponential-function, functional-equations

I had a rehearsal test today and got this question in the test that completely stumped me.

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a non constant continuous function such that
> $$(e^x-1)f(2x)=\left(e^{2x}-1\right)f(x)$$
> If $f'(0)=1$, then what are $f(x)$ and $f(2x)$?

**My try:**

I just differentiated both sides with respect to $x$ and made use of $f'(0)=1$, but that got me nowhere.

Please help me someone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does $e^{2x}-1 = (e^{x} - 1)(e^{x} + 1)$ help?

Comment: On using the logic of @Mattos and then differentiating the equation and making use of the fact that $f'(0)=1$, I'm getting $f(0)=0$, but that would mean $f(x)=x$ for every $x$ in the domain?

Comment: The easiest way is to just notice from how the $ x $ and $ 2 x $ appear on either side of the equation, that $ f(x) = e^x - 1 $ works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also attended the same test. Here's how I solved it . Its easier than you think it is.
First rearrange both sides
$$\frac{f(2x)}{(e^{2x}-1)}= \frac{f(x)}{(e^{x}-1)}$$

From this you can conclude that $f(x)= e^{x}-1$,[NOTE: Not necessarily $e^x-1$. Please refer Daniel Fischers comment below.]

Otherwise the above condition would cease to be true. Also, $f'(0) = 1$ holds true for the above function.

As it is an objective question paper this is the quickest (and apparently the only single method). Now you can solve for the options given in the question paper.

Note: This question was an MCQ in which multiple options are correct.

Comment: How do you know? Did you give this test too?

Comment: Yes @user38227 I gave it too. I also assume that you where pretty confused by seeing the options.

Comment: _How_ do you conclude $f(x) = e^x-1$ from $\frac{f(2x)}{e^{2x}-1} = \frac{f(x)}{e^x-1}$?

Comment: How did you solve the limits then? It actually is quite confusing.

Comment: @DanielFischer I noted that from the equality given, $f(x)$ must be of the form $k(e^x - 1)$, so that the equality holds true.Also $k=1$ from the fact that $f'(0)=1$. This may not be the only solution, of-course.But I have mentioned it as the quickest and simplest one I could find.

Comment: @user38227 It would be helpful if you add the given limits to the question itself so that I can include the solution in my answer. It will be helpful for other users as well.

Comment: The equality doesn't imply $f(x) = k(e^x-1)$, see the comments under TonyK's answer. Of course functions of that form satisfy the given relation, and depending on the options of the multiple choice, this may suffice. But one must use the differentiability of $f$ at $0$ to properly conclude that $f$ has that form without help from the multiple choice answers.

Comment: Thats correct @DanielFischer . But I believe the question is a difficult one as so many other functions can be found using the differentiability criteria, and you have included one yourself. But such questions are asked to develop the quick thinking of the student. Hence I thought the above could be the best solution, which helps the person who asked this.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $x\ne 0$, we have
$$\frac{f(2x)}{e^{2x}-1}=\frac{f(x)}{e^x-1}$$
So put $g(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{e^x-1}$ for $x\ne 0$. Then we have
$$g(2x)=g(x)$$
for all non-zero $x$. $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb R-\{0\}$, so we must have
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}
c_+,  & \text{if $x > 0$} \\
c_-, & \text{if $x < 0$}
\end{cases}$$
for some constants $c_+,c_-$.

(**Edited to add:** It's not that simple $-$ see Daniel Fischer's comment below.)

This gives us
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
c_+(e^x-1),  & \text{if $x > 0$} \\
c_-(e^x-1), & \text{if $x < 0$}
\end{cases}$$

By continuity of $f$, $c_+=c_-=c,$ say. So $f(x)=c(e^x-1)$ for all $x$.

I will leave the rest to you.

Comment: From $g(2x) = g(x)$ for $x\neq 0$ it does not follow that $g$ is locally constant. Consider $\sin \bigl(\frac{2\pi}{\log 2} \log \lvert x\rvert\bigr)$. You need the other conditions on $f$ to reach the conclusion.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Oh yes, you're quite right! And we even have that $f(x)=(e^x-1)\sin \bigl(\frac{2\pi}{\log 2} \log \lvert x\rvert\bigr)$ is continuous. So we also need the implied condition that $f$ is differentiable at $0$. But how do we use that? This question is difficult!

Comment: Yes indeed. @DanielFischer I also took up  the same a assumption which  TonyK used